How to make my default home directories (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures and Videos) the existent ones on my NTFS partition, on Ubuntu 24.04?
I've bought a new SSD in which did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.
I've tried this successfully on my previous SSD in which I had done this on Ubuntu 22.04, but I can't remember how I did it.
What I want to do is for Ubuntu to assume the Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures and Videos folders already existent on my NTFS drive as the default ones, leaving the ones on Ubuntu home folder intact.
Upon seeing a similar answer here, someone suggested "Ubuntu tweaks", but the app doesn't show or have what I need.

Confused. If it does not exist how do you know it does not have what you need?

You can just edit your ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file. See also this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107616/

Yes, you are confused. What are you even talking about?

I tried editing my Desktop folder on ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs to XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/media/nunovski2001/GST/Desktop" only to have the home contents plastered on my desktop. I don't understand hat I'm doing wrong.

Another alternative is to mount NTFS with fstab & link folders into /home. If keeping existing /home folders be sure to use different name/label/mount as you will over mount and not be able to see data in /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

There are multiple possibilities. Your NTFS partition obviously should be automatically mounted during startup through /etc/fstab for this to work.

By far the easiest way to connect these folders to existing folders on an NTFS partition will be to replace the current folders by symbolic links to the target folders on the NTFS partition.

Delete the current folders ("Documents", "Downloads", ...) in your home directory.

Create symbolic links to the target folders in your home directory. (You need to turn on the right-click menu item "Make link" in Files first to create symbolic links with Files)

Your ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs will now have been changed because you deleted the folder. Open it in a text editor, and restore the paths to their original value, e.g. .XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME" should read XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop", etc.


If you instead do this from the terminal, there will be no need to correct ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs.

Another approach requires you to be root. You can mount --bind the folders on the NTFS partition on the respective folders in your home partition.

In principle, you could edit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs so the XDG special folders instead point to the folders on your mounted NTFS partition. This is not recommended, because these folders then will not anymore live in your home directory, although they still can be reached easily from the left pane in the file manager.



"By far the easiest way to connect these folders to existing folders on an NTFS partition will be to replace the current folders by symbolic links to the target folders on the NTFS partition." And how do I do that, e.g. /home/nunovski2001/Desktop to /media/nunovski2001/GST/Desktop?
I tried editing my Desktop folder on ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs to XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/media/nunovski2001/GST/Desktop" only to have the home contents plastered on my desktop.

For symbolic links, see step 4 and 5 at the bottom of the accepted answer to this question.

#3 is easier than #1 ;) I;ve been doing that for decades :+  just replace them from the nautilus pane and use bookmarks/favorites OH 1 thing @NunoFonseca do NOT do that with the snap directory... that one requires ext

I advised using the terminal. You also can use the file manager, but once the links are in place, you will need to repair your ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs back to how it initially was, e.g. XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME" -> XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop". I will add that in the anwer.

I figured out a pretty simple solution to my question.

Create a subfolder in your /mnt folder and give it any name you wish (mine is the UUID number, i.e.  /mnt/01D266B54B2782C0). Find said UUID number in your Disks app when you click on any partition.

Still on that app, click on the wheel below any partition to Edit Mount Options.

While there, uncheck "User Session Defaults" and insert as the Mount Point the folder path you created on step 1, /mnt/01D266B54B2782C0. Click ok and reboot.

Go to ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs and replace every $HOME/ with /mnt/01D266B54B2782C0 in every directory you want to change, i.e. XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/mnt/01D266B54B2782C0/Videos"


